# Godot 3.4: Quest System using Dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, 2d, godot, gdscript

I took this to the Godot Reddit first, but honestly it's not much help imo. A lot of questions go unanswered there. So here I am.

As the title says, Im making a quest system in godot 2d using nested dictionaries. Ive seen people use Nodes, Classes or otherwise for their quest systems, and a few dictionary based ones out there. I chose dictionaries as I know them the best(still isnt a whole lot, or i probably wouldnt be here asking this lol) And my quest system is set up like so:
QuestBase --> QuestHandler --> PlayerData

QuestBase is a giant dictionary of all available quests in the game.
PlayerData is a giant dictionary of all the player stats(including active, completed, or failed quests)
and QuestHandler takes a questName in a function to Copy the quest(questName) from QuestBase dict into the PlayerData.quests_active dict.(quests_active is a dictionary of quests(also dictionaries) inside of the PlayerData dictionary lol) But i cant seem to get it to work. I've done it a couple different ways now, including the way the Godot documentation states on how to add Dinctionaries into dictionaries. Please help, this is the error I get from QuestHandler:

```
Invalid set index 'tutorialQuest' (on base: 'Nil') with value of type 'Dictionary'
```

QuestBase:

```
var storyQuests = {
    "tutorialQuest":{
        "name" : "Your First Steps",#Name of the Quest
        "desc" : "Get to know your environment and learn the ropes.",#Description of the Quest
        "level" : 1, #Required level before player can accept quest
        "questType" : 0, #0=Story Quest || 1=Side Quest || 2=Repeateable Quest
        "taskType": 0, #0=Progressive(task must be completed in order) || 1=Synchronous(tasks can be completed in any order, and all at once)
        "tasks":{#Dictionary of Quest's Tasks
            "task1":{
                "text":"Talk to Bjorn",#Text to display in Quest log
                "type":0,#0=Talk,1=Slay,2=Fetch,3=Deliver,4=Collect,5=Goto
                "quantity":0,#Determines the amount to complete task for Slay, Fetch, and Collect
                "target":"Bjorn",#Determines Who to talk to, or who to slay, or what to collect.
                "completed":false#Is this task complete?
                },
            "task2":{
                "text":"Talk to Bjorn",
                "type":"Talk",
                "target":"Bjorn",
                "completed":false
                },
            "task3":{
                "text":"Talk to Bjorn",
                "type":"Talk",
                "target":"Bjorn",
                "completed":false
                }
            },
        "itemReward":{
                "items":["Sword", "Basic Elixer"],#Names of items to give
                "amount":[1, 5]#Amount of each item to give, respectively.
            },
        "expReward":{
                "skill":["Forestry","Smithing"],#Names of skills to add Exp to
                "amount": [100,100] #Amount to add to each skill, respectively. 
                #1st number will increase first skill in "skill", etc...
            },
        "Complete":false,
        "Failed":false
        }
```

}

PlayerData:

```
var playerData = {
    ... irrelevant player data...

    #Quests
    "quests_active": {"blank":"blank"},
    "quests_completed": {},
    "quests_failed": {},
```

and Finally, Quest Handler:

```
func startQuest(questName: String):
var active_quests = PlayerData.playerData.get("quests_active")
if QuestBase.storyQuests.has(questName):
    var questCopy = QuestBase.storyQuests.get(questName).duplicate(true)
    PlayerData.playerData.get("quests_active")[questName] = questCopy  #.quests_active.append(questCopy)
    #print("Story Quest Started: " + PlayerData.playerData.QuestsActive.get(questName).get("name"))
elif QuestBase.sideQuests.has(questName):
    var questCopy = QuestBase.sideQuests.get(questName).duplicate(true)
    active_quests.append(questCopy)
    #print("Side Quest Started: " + PlayerData.playerData.QuestsActive.get(questName).get("name"))
else:
    print("Quest Doesn't Exist! Check Spelling!")
```

Comment: What line is giving the error? - Edit: By the way, `active_quests` is a dictionary, right? So, I believe you should not be using `append` with it.

Comment: in QuestHandler: PlayerData.playerData.get("quests_active")[questName] = questCopy      
.
The append I was playing with to see if i could turn it into an array and make it work that way, no dice. The second half of the if statement never gets called yet because I dont try and start a side quest. Once i get one quest working, i can get the rest to work.

Comment: So that means Godot is saying that `PlayerData.playerData.get("quests_active")` is null. Which could be either that `PlayerData.playerData` has the key `"quests_active"` and its value is null, or it does not have the key. Yet, I don't see how either case could be.

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought too, so I added the "blank":"blank" to active_quests and it still returns null

Comment: I threw in a print(PlayerData.playerData.quests_active) to see what I would get, and it is indeed null as in nonexistant. It through a null error. How can this be though???

Comment: My best guess is that `playerData` does not refer to the dictionary you think it does. In fact I was about to suggest to put a breakpoint and look at it. Another thing that comes to mind is to type the variables, which could help identify problems (although it is not incredibly helpful with dictionaries because they are always of variant). Anyway, as alternative consider having `quests_active`, `quests_completed`, `quests_failed` and so on as their own variables instead of being inside of `playerData`, so you could do `PlayerData.quests_active` and so on.

Comment: That was my next course of action if I could not get this solved. Of course that brings me to the problem of using file.store_var() for multiple variables. What I want is to store everything the player needs to save in a single file. Inventory, quests, skills, stats, etc.

Comment: What is `PlayerData` (Not to be confused with `PlayerData.playerData`)? I would consider serializing `PlayerData` instead of `PlayerData.playerData`. Also, don't you have multiple variables already (e.g. `PlayerData.playerData` and `QuestBase.storyQuests`)? If you already have to deal with multiple variables, adding more variables should not be a big deal. And if `store_var` does not work for you, consider using `str2var` and `var2str` with `store_pascal_string` and `get_pascal_string`.

Comment: I am an idiot. I totally forgot that I have a copy of PlayerData called newPlayerData for new games, that makes PlayerData an exact copy of newPlayerData(stats in newPlayerData are never changed, and are always starting stats). Well, I made edits to PlayerData and forgot to update newPlayerData, so of course active_quests wasnt found, it wasnt included in newPlayerData.... It works now, thank you!

Comment: PlayerData is my singleton script where the variable dictionary playerData is held